# Perl backtick behaves differently than console commands

Tags: perl

So, I'm writing a Perl script which at one point needs to process the output of another script.  I tried to do this by calling the script in backticks:

```
 my @output = `scriptName`;
```

I have tested the script I want to call in backticks, and it works just fine--in the same shell I'm calling my script in, even.  But when I call it as part of the script, it produces no output.  The variable is left empty.

I've tried executing the command with system(), but there is still no output.  I have no idea why.  However, the specific arguments I'm passing into the script have caused me problems before until I fixed my PATH variable.  Does calling a script through a Perl script result in different environment variables somehow?

Edit:  Okay, here's a potential issue.  I tried using backticks and system() to print out my PATH variable, and both of them are coming up blank.  Is my Perl script unable to use my PATH for some reason?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The environment for the child process is identical to that of the parent. See if it works for you with a standard command-line utility, like `ls`. Also check that the script you're trying to run isn't sending its output to `STDERR`, as all you will get from the backticks is whatever is sent to `STDOUT`. You could also try `my @output = \`perl -e "print 'working'"\``

Comment: I am in a linux environment, and have confirmed that both backticks and system() work with "ls".  I haven't tried STDERR yet, but I will.

Comment: PATH, like all environment variables, is inherited from the parent process.

Comment: Remember backticks will interpolate `$PATH` as if it were a perl variable, before passing the resulting string to the shell. (Do you `use warnings`?) The correct perl syntax to print your `PATH` through backticks is `\`echo \$PATH\`` (with backslash) or `qx'echo $PATH'` (with single quotes).

Comment: A program run by cron won't have your interactive session environment. You haven't given us enough details. If you think the environment is changing, start investigating that. Inspect values at the start of the program to see if they are what you think they are, and move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of problems such as these, is difference in relative paths. I have a tendency of using absolute paths for that reason.

In addition, it sounds to me like your subscript might be printing to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT`. Backticks only capture STDOUT, so you need to do a redirect with the help of `2>&1`

```
my @output = `scriptName 2>&1`;
```

**NB:** The redirect doesn't work with all shells (I believe it was tcsh that didn't support it back when i had a similar problem). Bash takes the redirect just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Environment isn't your problem, unless you're explicitly adjusting it within perl, prior to calling your script. My suggestion would be - double check permissions on your script, and check relative paths. I note you don't have `./scriptName` - so if it's not in your path, perl won't be able to find it either.